# How to keep the original value unchanged in MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have the following multi-binding for my `TextBlock`

```
<Multibinding Converter="{StaticResource myconv}">
 <Binding Path="Property1" />
 <Binding Path="Property2" />
 <Binding Path="Property3" />
</Multibinding>
```

Here is my converter code

```
public class PropertiesSelectorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Where(v => v != null).FirstOrDefault();

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Problem**
Now what I would like to do here is when all of the `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3` are null, I want `TextBlock` to retain its original value. How do I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special value of `Binding` called `Binding.DoNothing`:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var value = values.Where(v => v != null).FirstOrDefault();
    return value == null ? Binding.DoNothing : value;
}
```